# Why is 'vals' being reset to zero every iteration of this while loop?

Tags: c

I am writing some code to pack small integer values into a regular int

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMVALS 6
#define SIZE 5
#define MAX 31

int main() {
int vals = 0;
short curVal, idx = 0;

while(idx != NUMVALS) {
  scanf("%d",&curVal);
  printf("Vals pre shift: %.8X\n",vals);
  vals <<= SIZE;
  printf("Vals post shift: %.8X\n",vals);
  vals |= curVal;
  printf("Vals post new set:%.8X\n\n",vals);
  idx++;
}
```

When I run this small check, with input string

1 2 3 4 5 6

I get output akin to this

```
Vals pre shift: 00000000
Vals post shift: 00000000
Vals post new set:00000001

Vals pre shift: 00000000
Vals post shift: 00000000
Vals post new set:00000002
```

For all six. Why is vals resetting to zero every loop? It doesn't look like I'm touching it at all, but clearly something is resetting it.

Comment: At minimum, this is a problem: `scanf("%d",&curVal);`.  Your `curVal` is a `short`, but you are telling `scanf()` that it's getting a pointer to `int`.  You want this format, instead: `"%hd"`.  Or else just make `curVal` an `int`.

Comment: Ah, that appears to have fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier in `scanf`. This causes undefined behaviour.  One possibility might be that `scanf` wrote 4 bytes to the 2-byte location of `curVal`, and the "extra" 2 bytes clobbered `vals`.

For a `short`, use `%hd`. Another option would be to change `curVal` to be an `int`.

---

Another potential problem is with `vals <<= SIZE;`. Shifting a `1` into the sign bit also causes undefined behaviour.  It might behave roughly sanely on common systems, but all the same, it's easily fixed by making `vals` have type `unsigned int`.

Comment: For this particular implementation, the only case that would cause a 1 to be shifted that far would be a separate bug in the code, since I'm only shifting 30 total bits. I'll change it anyways though

Comment: @EvanCooper If the first entry were some fairly large number instead of `1`, then the overflow scenario could be reached

Comment: That's what the `#define MAX 31` is for, it's just not implemented yet